# Ruby: The Meta-class and Class Variables

Tags: ruby, syntax

I've been looking at some articles that say that [class variables are bad in Ruby](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/01/nubygems_dont_use_class_variab_1.html). They suggest using the meta-class (or singleton class). This is my sample code

```
class Joe
  class << self # here we're putting methods in Joe's "meta class" 
    attr_accessor :foo
  end
  def self.foo2
  end
  def self.foo2=value
  end
end

puts Joe.singleton_methods
```

I understand that foo and foo2 are essentially the same, though there's no way to use attr_accesor with foo2.

I don't get what's up with the `class << self syntax`. Is there some kind of concatenation happening, or... what is it? Is that some kind of extension, inheritance or monkey-patching?

**Edit (Bonus):** While I'm here, is there any way to cache data on a view helper? I have tried using this class << self thing, but the helper methods do not find the accessor.

Comment: Just realized that I have to shut off class caching to get the helpers to cache their values in class vars. Easier than I thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `class<< foo` syntax stands for "in the definition of the class of foo". So if you do this:

```
class Foo
   class << self
     # class method defined as INSTANCE method
     # the only instance being Foo (the class)
     def boo
       ...
     end
   end
end
```

this is analogous to

```
class Foo
  def self.boo #class method
  end
end
```

In the same vein, you can grab a separate object and extend it with methods

```
class << some_object
   def something # adds a method to some_object ONLY
   end
end
```

So when you do  "within class of self" within a class definition, you are jumping "one level up"
into the definition of your "eigen"-class (or "metaclass") where you can call stuff in the context
of your "class as an instance of this thing I am in". So the class methods of
your class become instance methods and can be defined and treated as such, and 
module includes will affect the class methods no the instance methods.

For your case:

```
class Joe
  # here we're putting methods in the "class of class"
  class << self
    include ClassMethodsForJoe
    attr_accessor :foo
  end
end
Joe.foo # this is the method we made
```

Comment: WOW. That's the answer I needed.

Comment: Good answer.  You started with, '"class<< foo" stands for "in the definition of the class of foo".  @sepp2k, in his answer, said "The `class << foo` opens the singleton class of foo..." (an expression one often sees).  Both of these seem a bit vague to me.  Isn't it more accurate to say, "class<< foo sets self equal to the singleton class of foo"?

Comment: I've done it because once you know what "eigenclass" or "singleton class" is you don't ask a question like this one. I've found both of these notions only useful for people who _already know_ what they mean in Ruby - and I've found them not helpful in explaining the whole `class of class` construct.

Answer (score 6):

The `class << foo` opens the singleton class of foo, which is the class that foo is the only instance of (and which implicitly inherits foo's "real" class). So it's a kind of extension (you're adding methods to one specific object that are not defined by that object's class). It's not monkey-patching because you're only affecting that one object and not any other object of that class.

Note that `def foo.bar` is merely a shortcut for

```
class <<foo
  def bar
```

i.e. it does the same thing behind the scenes. The `<<` has nothing to do with the `<<` method. It's just part of the syntax.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I've edited the question with a bonus (really to not explain myself again in another question)... how can I use this in a view helper.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to caching data in view helpers you could use [memoization](http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/09/20/a-guide-to-memoization).

Comment: I get it now. But more importantly, I need to shut off caching in the config.